# autossh creating many processes every time

Tags: linux, debian, process, autossh

I'm using autossh to connect to a reverse SSH tunnel. I run it from startup.

However, I was facing problems in that the tunnel sometimes goes down.

I created a script which checks if the tunnel is actually working , and if not do other stuff like restart the modem etc.

The only way I seem to be able to check if the tunnel is working is by using the autossh command again and checking the reply.

```
autossh -M 0 -N -q -o ServerAliveInterval=20 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 HMzg8fspYG8SS1oJ7Jl6bkDnT2lYrB@fw1.sshreach.me -i id_rsa -R 13238:localhost:22 -v
```

I just noticed tho that every time I use this autossh command, it starts a new auto process. There are so many autossh processes running now. This is obviously not good.

There are two questions :

1) Is there a better way to verify if my tunnel is working without using the autossh command again? (I couldn't find another way)

2) The other option I suppose is to kill the processes in my script which are not used and just have the one autossh process. However, How do I find the pid of a process if there are many of them with the name autossh?

Comment: The point of autossh is you not having to launch processes manually, I think. Could it be possible that you are using SSH to tunnel something that should be tunnelled on other way?

Comment: I know, but, this is the only way to solve my problem. I need to check with autossh in a script if the tunnel is actually open by reading the responses, if not, then restart the modem to solve it. I don't understand why this is, but it fixes my issue